# Error message: Function is not callable, not sure what is wrong?

Tags: python, algorithm, ccxt, bitmex

```
def smaShort(self):
    while True:
        ohlcv_candles = bitmex2.bitmex.fetch_ohlcv(self, symbol= 'XBTUSD', timeframe= '5m')
        mas = []
        mas = ohlcv_candles.rolling(window=5).mean()
    return mas#[-1]
```

when trying to call smaShort function

```
logger.info("sma short value:" (self.smaShort()))
```

I get the error smaShort is not callable, anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The code you posted is not runnable, we can't verify the error.

Comment: i used the ccxt bitmex library to get the fetch_ohlcv function, i hope this helps clarify a bit

Comment: You also dont have a break, you have an infinite loop

Comment: @VarunReddy The code you posted is not runnable, we can't verify the error.

Comment: Did you define an instance attribute with the same name?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import ccxt

exchange = ccxt.bitmex({
    'enableRateLimit': True,  # required by the Manual
})

ohlcv = exchange.fetch_ohlcv('BTC/USD', '1m')

df = pd.DataFrame (ohlcv)
df[4].rolling(window=5).mean()  # OHLCV, C (closing price) has index 4
```

1. Bitmex does not have a `XBTUSD` symbol, it's a market *id* not a *symbol*, as explained in the Manual: https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/wiki/Manual#symbols-and-market-ids. The correct symbol is `BTC/USD`.
2. Also, according to CCXT Manual, the call to `bitmex.fetch_ohlcv` will return the following structure: https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/wiki/Manual#ohlcv-structure.
3. The ohlcv structure is a plain array/list of arrays with OHLCV candle values, not a Pandas DataFrame, so you can't call `.rolling(window=5).mean()` on a list, you have to convert it to a DataFrame first, like shown above (or in any other way supported by Pandas).